# How to sum column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i am getting table like this when run some query with joins. The problem is the columns and rows of this table vary dynamically based on master table. So i cant decide the column and rows.

```
    Select
    ..
    ..
    (20GP+20HD+20RF+30FR+30HD+30GP+30GP+40HD+40FR+40RF) as total
    from 
    tablename
```

if i use this above query then i need to edit the query each time so instead of this above query please some one tell me how to do this.

now i need to sum each columns in this table and have to show in separate column Total

```
------------------------------------------------------..etc..,-----
location|20GP|20HD|20RF|30FR|30HD|30GP|30GP|40HD|40FR|..etc..,40RF|
------------------------------------------------------..etc..,-----
   UAE  |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |..etc..,  1 |
   USA  |  2 |  3 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |..etc..,  0 |
    .......,
    .......,
    ........etc,

   IND  |  0 |  0 |  0 | 2 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 | ..etc.., 1 | 
------------------------------------------------------..etc..,----
```

just shown below expected output

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
location|20GP|20HD|20RF|30FR|30HD|30GP|30GP|40HD|40FR|40RF|total
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   UAE  |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  4
   USA  |  2 |  3 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  7
    .......,
    .......,
    ........etc,

   IND  |  0 |  0 |  0 | 2 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |   5
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

please some one tell how to do this

Comment: Cant you work higher up the chain?To sum the columns before creating this table?It sounds like a bad design

Answer (score -1):

Hey try following query to get column list and prepare string of query from it and execute that string by preparing statement. you just verify your column name pattern in regular expression.

```
(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', group_concat(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR '+'), ' as total FROM Test2') INTO @sql
FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (select database()) 
AND   `TABLE_NAME`   = 'Test2'
AND   `COLUMN_NAME` REGEXP '^[0-9]');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
Execute stmt1;
```